# Rspec errors: Unable to find (erb) to read failed line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

my Rspec in rails suddenly got weird errors.

it said

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find (erb) to read failed line

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
 # (erb):63:in `get_binding'
```

to most of my test spec and it said the same thing, any one can help me please? thank you :)

note: i`m using rspec-rails 3.4.2 and my version rails is 4.2.5.2

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. The error you've copied is not the one you say you have... `undefined method id for nil:NilClass` means you're calling the `id` method on something that is nil. Can you show us a bit more of the stacktrace? you may need to go and look in your test logs to find that (look in the `log` directory) - you'll see a long list of filenames. we want the first few of those so we can figure out which file and which line of code is causing the error. Please edit your question and paste the filenames in there not in comments, because code-formatting in comments is awful

Comment: Also - your rspec output should tell you what spec is failing, and what line it is... can you look at the output and copy all of that in your question too, also copy the *relevant* spec code into your question for us to look at

Comment: 1) have you changed something recently that involves an `id` ? if so - go find that and make sure there's not a syntax error 2) otherwise, (temporarily) remove all your specs except the simplest one, and then *show me the code* :) because I literally can't help you debug code that I can't see ;)

Comment: i haven`t change something that involves an id i think.

the weirdest thing is when i empty my test code like this

  it "can comment" do

  end

it`s still got the same errors

Comment: oh, i think i got a clue, 

when i remove my fixtures, the error is gone, there is something wrong with my fixtures

Comment: awesome! yeah, I find that stripping the test code down to just what's breaking can sometimes be a real help. If it starts working again, you just start adding tests one by one until it breaks... and that's the one that's breaking it ;)

Comment: it works now, just remove the '<%= Product.where.not(info:nil).first.id %>'
in fixtures file ( .yml ), it becomes green

but when i add it again now, it still becomes green, i dunno what happen in the last error, it is still the same code

Comment: `Product.where.not(info:nil).first.id` will explode with an error... if there isn't a product returned by `Product.where.not(info:nil).first`